# css image max-height has no effect unless I change the max-width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am a fullstack developer but css is my my weak point so I decided to put more effort on it. I have a weird situation and could not figure out why. The issue is I could not adjust the image height and wide properly.  I m using reactstrap, bootstrap and scss but i make sure that bootstrap code will not overwrite my css:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../styles/main.scss";
```

here is the part of html:

```
  <Col md="6">
            <div className="hero-section">
              <div className={`flipper ${isFlipping ? "isFlipping" : ""}`}>
                <div className="front">
                  <div className="hero-section-content">
                    <h2> Full Stack Web Developer </h2>
                    <div className="hero-section-content-intro">
                      Have a look at my portfolio and job history.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <img
                    alt="programming welcome picture"
                    className="image"
                    src="/images/original.png"
                  />
                  <div className="shadow-custom">
                    <div className="shadow-inner"> </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
    </Col>
```

here is the related css code:

```
.hero-section {
  h2 {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }


  perspective: 10rem;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 40rem;
  position: relative;

  &-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 360px;
    left: 6%;
    z-index: 1;

    &-intro {
      font-size: 17px;
    }
  }
}


 .image {
  max-width: 100%;
  // background-size: cover;
  max-height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}
```

with this I have this:
[image]

however with this .image

```
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  // background-size: cover;
  // max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}
```

I have same view. height changes if I change the width but i just want to change the height.

image css i am having this

with this .image

```
.image {
  max-height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

i am getting text outside the image :( even though the max-width: 100% it is not as wide as first image :(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]**: I forgot I am the only one on this earth that allowed to have a well working stackblitz so just in case here is the code :

```
<div className="content">
    <h2>FullStack developerdfghbdfg</h2>
    <p>Were you looking for something like this ?</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS part :

```
.content {
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300'); /* you need an HD image to do this */
  background-size: cover; /* because thiswill strech your image */
  color: red; /* pretty disgusting yeah ! */
}
```

---

Are you looking for something like this ? [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zy6ftz?file=style.css)

If not, can you provide the shape of your image please ? I mean, is it a loooong vertical image full of blue, or is it just the boy and screen and books and stuff and a background color set to the same blue for your container ?

Answer (score 0):

> why is the text outside the image?

**TL;TD:** the image is narrower than 40rem.

Here's the too long to read version:

by setting `max-width` to `100%`, the image would allow itself to take `100%` of its intrinsic width, but since the `height` is set to `auto`, the image width would be dictated by the intrinsic height of the image, making it a fractional width from 100%.

> why is image wider and taller from your 1st scenario below?

```
.image {
  // allows the image to take up 100% of its width
  max-width: 100%;
  // allows the image to take up 100% of its height
  max-height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

the image is taking up the intrinsic width/height values since the `<img>` element is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) type and its [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) css property is not defined.

---

**resolution 1**

set `div.hero-section` to a fixed width and height, like this

```
.hero-section {
  // ie. height/width can be anything you like
  height: 20rem;
  width: 40rem;
  ...
}
```

then set the `object-fit` property to `cover` in the `.image` class

```
.image {
  ...
  object-fit: cover
}
```

---

**resolution 2**

use the image as a background image. Take out the `.img` class and the image markup entirely from HTML. Set the `.hero-section` css like this

```
.hero-section {
  ...
  width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("/images/original.png");
  ...

}
```

I have a mock of the code in my codesandbox below

[image: Edit async-mountain-0qkgc]